How to use FlyWay together with Quarkus and mongoDB?
We are about to start a new major project in my department and we really would like to manage changes to our mongodb (e.g. creation of indixes, data migration, etc.) in an orderly way. I have looked into FlyWay and it seems to cover most of our needs in this area. However, I have not been able to setup FlyWay in combination with Quarkus and mongoDB, which both are set technologies since we have successfully used them together for several years now and have a lot of experience with that. What I really like about FlyWay is that we can define everything in JavaScript, using the full potential of scripting stuff for the database.
We are using Quarkus 3.2 and mongoDB Version 6. Eventually we will deploy our micro services in a cloud environment.
I have looked at the Quarkus documentation regarding FlyWay and I have looked at the documentation from FlyWay regarding mongoDB.
I have defined the dependencies in out pom.xml like this, getting the JDBC driver directly from org.mongodb since :
[...]
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
[...]

For our regular communication with the database, we define the connection string in application.properties:
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost:27018/<database>

FlyWay does not seem to be able to use this, according to the documentation it uses the configured datasource from Quarkus. So I tried to set that as well. But here I can't set the kind of datasource we are dealing with since mongodb is not supported as a datasource:
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=???

I then tried to set the URL directly for FlyWay, without defining a data source via Quarkus means. Configuring FlyWay should be as easy as this:
quarkus.flyway.jdbc-url=jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27018/<dbname>
quarkus.flyway.username=<username>
quarkus.flyway.password=<password>
quarkus.flyway.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.flyway.locations=flyway

For the Quarkus integration of FlyWay, I can't define the suffix for the migration files. However, according to the documentation for using FlyWay together with mongoDB, it should be fine having the JavaScript in an .sql file (even though it does not look nice to me). If this is true for the Quarkus integration as well, is another question. Now, defining my migration file in the directory src/main/resources/flyway does not seem to have any effect.
Am I completely on the wrong track here? Can I use FlyWay together with mongoDB without using the Quarkus integration but still deploy in a container? Or is what I am trying do, simply not possible at the moment?

I just realized that what I am trying out is a preview feature of FlyWay: https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/supported-databases/mongodb
So maybe what I am trying to do is not possible?

Might not help you but from my experience I prefer to use flyway and db creation/migration as an independent process without trying to integrate it with quarkus.
So what we do in every release that affects the data model is:
1.Deploy DB
2.Use an existing container with flyway that connects to the DB, update it with the latest scripts and run it to execute the migration
3. Our components are agnostic to how the scripts are managed and updated only if there's a change to the data model that impacts any access
